# How to load an external html file into a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to load a html file into the div on a button click. When i click on create button it should load 'createarray.html' file into div tabcontent.

This is my html file:

```
<div class="tab">
<button class="tablinks" onclick="createarray.html" id= "defaultOpen">Creation</button>
<button class="tablinks" onclick="insertarray.html">Insertion</button>
<button class="tablinks" onclick="deletearray.html">Deletion</button>  
</div>
<div id="Create" class="tabcontent">
</div>
<div id="Insert" class="tabcontent">
</div>
<div id="delete" class="tabcontent">
</div>
```

This is my java script:

```
$.ajax({
url : "createarray.html",
dataType: "html",
success : function (data) {
    $("#create").html(data);
}
});
$.ajax({
url : "insertarray.html",
dataType: "html",
success : function (data) {
    $("#insert").html(data);
}
});
$.ajax({
url : "deletearray.html",
dataType: "html",
success : function (data) {
    $("#delete").html(data);
}
});
```

Can someone please help me with this please?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making `ajax` request, you can use jQuery's `load` method. Here's the documentation [link](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

**Sample code**

```
<button class="tablinks" data-url="insertarray.html" data-target="create">Insertion</button>
```

```js
$(function(){
    $(".tablinks").click(function(){
        var url = $(this).attr("data-url");
        var target = "#" + $(this).attr("data-target");
        $(target).load(url);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
    <div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="createarray()" id= "defaultOpen">Creation</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="insertarray()">Insertion</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="deletearray()">Deletion</button>  
    </div>
    <div id="create" class="tabcontent">
    </div>
    <div id="insert" class="tabcontent">
    </div>
    <div id="delete" class="tabcontent">
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
function createarray(){
$.ajax({
url : "createarray.html",
success : function (data) {
    $("#create").html(data);
}
});
}

function insertarray(){
$.ajax({
url : "insertarray.html",
success : function (data) {
    $("#insert").html(data);
}
});
}

function deletearray(){
$.ajax({
url : "deletearray.html",
success : function (data) {
    $("#delete").html(data);
}
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [onclick attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/onclick) accepts Javascript - `onclick="createarray.html"` etc isn't right. I'm assuming you'd like to load your HTML when those buttons are clicked. Your Javascript is a little repetitive too so we could put it in a function like this instead:

```
function loadHtml(file){
    $.ajax({
        url : file+"array.html",
        dataType: "html",
        success : function (data) {
            $("#"+file).html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

We can do better with this though. It's mostly replicating the jQuery load method, so you could use that instead:

```
function loadHtml(file){
    $("#" + file).load(file + "array.html");
}
```

Which you would then call from your `onclick` attribute like this:

```
<button class="tablinks" onclick="loadHtml('create')" id= "defaultOpen">Creation</button>
<button class="tablinks" onclick="loadHtml('insert')">Insertion</button>
<button class="tablinks" onclick="loadHtml('delete')">Deletion</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your use of `onclick` will be causing errors as the contents are expected to be valid JS code.

To achieve what you need you can use an unobtrusive event handler on the `button` elements to along with `data` attributes to store their custom data. In the event handler you can then `load()` the required content in to the given target. Try this:

```
<button type="button" class="tablinks defaultOpen" data-url="createarray.html" data-target="#create">Creation</button>
<button type="button" class="tablinks" data-url="insertarray.html" data-target="#insert">Insertion</button>
<button type="button" class="tablinks" data-url="deletearray.html" data-target="#delete">Deletion</button>
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('.tablinks').click(function() {
    var target = $(this).data('target');
    $(target).load($(this).data('url'));
  });
});
```

Note that I amended `defaultOpen` to a class as it makes more sense semantically.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
  $("#idOfWhereYouClick").click(function(){
  $("#idOfDivWhereYouWantToLoad").load("yourPage.html");
});
```