# how do I load an external html file into a div on a multi div page

Tags: jquery, html

I have seen answers for loading into one div such as this

```
<button class="tablinks" data-url="insertarray.html" data-target="create">Insertion</button>
```

```js
$(function(){
  $(".tablinks").click(function(){
    var url = $(this).attr("data-url");
    var target = "#" + $(this).attr("data-target");
    $(target).load(url);
  });
});
```

[See Rory McCrossan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42958366/519413).

But I have a master menu that sends sub-menus into three different  DIV.  Then these 3 submenus load a file in a corresponding DIV (submenu-A sends to view-A -to view the html file ; submenu-B sends to view-B submenu-C sends to view-C.

Im learning and I wondered if

1. `data-url="insertarray.html"` this must be the html file I want to load
2. `data-target="create"` is this the ID of the DIV?
3. Does this solution work only on buttons?

(My menus use LI commands that use the radio button to make them click-able.  The sub-menus can have up to 1200 links
The master menu has 26 links to class subjects
the secondary master menu has about 200 links (to the submenus)
This is a free educational tool I made to help my students.   Its in frames going to flexbox as soon as I learn enough jquery to load the files )

Sorry I cant figure out how to use the code command to set off the code.  I'll keep trying to figure that out so my questions are well formatted.  Please forgive as I learn how.  Thank you.

Comment: 1. Yes 2. Yes 3. No

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186/286047 _“I'll keep trying to figure that out so my questions are well formatted”_ - you might as well have made that effort _before_ you asked.

Comment: 1. That's correct 2. Yes it is, although the value can be any valid selector, not just an id one. 3. No, it works on any element which accepts a `click` event handler.